# Internet Explorer to Firefox javascript migration library - does one exist?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, migration, cross-browser

I am working on a legacy ASP.NET web site that is highly dependent on Internet Explorer.  I would like to migrate it to non-IE browsers.  I know there are a large amount of differences (as detailed at quirksmode.org, etc.), so I'm searching for a javascript library that can help minimize the amount of source I'd have to change.

I'm hoping that my lack of success in finding such a beast so far means that I'm just a bad google-er, and not that I'm just going to have to slog through coming up with replacements/workarounds for all of IE's proprietary functionality that this site currently uses (it uses quite a bit).

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Frankly you should probably convert the site to a well known multi-platform javascript library such as [ExtJs](http://extjs.com/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

This'll let you standardize your javascript to work on all browsers (including ie)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're going to have to slug through a little.  I don't know much about IE, but I'm really happy when I use **jQuery**.  There are many functions and modules that expand the functionality available.  And there is lots of help here on **Stack Overflow** and at *[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/)*.

Good luck!